# Add a method breakpoint to all methods of a class in EclipseIDE

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, is there a way you can set Method Breakpoints on all the methods of the class without going to individual methods? The motivation behind is that, any time a method gets hit, it would go to that method in debug mode.

Answer (score 145):

The fastest way is to go to the "Outline" view and select all of the methods you want, right-click and click "Toggle Method Breakpoint"

Comment: Adding to this, you can set a keyboard shortcut for Toggle Method Breakpoint so you can just key through the outline.

Comment: If the menu entry is missing, you may have selected an inner class (like a `Comparator` or `Filter` used in some method) or a class field, too.  Keep the *Ctrl* key pressed and deselect any of them, then it willl show up.

Comment: Could also be caused by an abstract method

Answer (score 8):

No direct way that I know of.
But if you add **[AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/)** (that is  aspect-oriented extension), you could write [an "advice"](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Introducing-AJDT/article.html) that you would set on each method of a Class when entering them on runtime.

[image]

You could then set a breakpoint in that advice code.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, we can add breakpoint at **every method of a class** at once.

In your **Project Explorer --> (go to the class)** expand the class. It will give you a list of declaration and methods. There,

1. Select all the methods using `ctrl`.
2. Right click and select `Toggle Method Breakpoint`.

That's all. Which ever method you select, a breakpoint will be placed.