# Automate setting breakpoints on all methods

Tags: eclipse, debugging, automation, intellij-idea, breakpoints

Is there a way to automate setting breakpoints in eclipse/idea on all methods in a given class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a method breakpoint to all methods of a class in EclipseIDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685445/add-a-method-breakpoint-to-all-methods-of-a-class-in-eclipseide)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Outline view (Eclipse), you can select all methods, right click and choose "Toggle method breakpoint"

Comment: do we have same ease in android studio for this task,