# Is there any way to set breakpoints on all methods of a class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any way to set breakpoints on all methods of a given class?

I have a huge (2300 lines) legacy class and I need to set breakpoints on all method calls to understand how this mess works.

Comment: How about just adding one breakpoint and stepping through the code? I don't know the keycode for "Next step", but I'm certain Intellij can do that. Also, Java has absolutely noting to do with JavaScript, removing the JS tag.

Comment: @Cerbrus the methods of this class might be called only infrequently and then one cannot just step through the code.

Comment: At least Eclipse can do it, it would be disappointing if Idea couldn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076385/automate-setting-breakpoints-on-all-methods

Comment: I am working on an app where there are multiple services. When you submit a request, it calls multiple services which itself may call multiple services. I could look at the access log and trace the requests to methods based on mappings. But this is a time consuming process. Having a feature which puts break points in all methods within a service would be a great feature for me. Having a break at exception like Visual Studio has, would have been another great related feature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have discovered workaround :

1. I have set "Toggle Brakepoint" hotkey to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

2. After that you can click on first method

3. Use "Toggle Brakepoint"

4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> - goto Next Method. ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> - goto Previous Method. )

5. Repeat 3 step.

Comment: what if you have 10 classes and 30 methods in each class, that you want to put breakpoints to.

Answer (score 63):

You can follow the steps below:

> 1. Run -> View breakpoints -> Add -> Java Method Breakpoints
> 2. Class pattern -> full reference of your class *(e.g., mypackage.MyClass)*
> 3. Method Name -> * *(i.e., asterisk wild card)*

[image: Example]

Comment: @Malachiasz I re-tried it on the Intellij IDEA community edition and it works fine. The debugger stops on every explicit or implicit method invocation of the class. I guess you have to be careful with the package name (it's case sensitive) or the fields values (Class pattern ->  full reference of your class, Method Name -> * ).

Comment: This method works. To quickly obtain full class reference path open your class, right click on its name and select copy reference.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to Sergey Senkov's answer, but without hotkeys.

In the structure view, click on the first method. Repeat the following for each method:

1. <kbd>Context Menu Key</kbd>
2. <kbd>M</kbd> to toggle the method breakpoint.
3. <kbd>Down</kbd>

Comment: This also requires certain hotkeys to be defined.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin for idea:
[Simple Toggle All Method Breakpoint](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9661-simple-toogle-all-method-breakpoint).

It allows you to breakpoint all methods / clear all method's breakpoints in one click from context menu on class in Project view.

Comment: Need for Android Studio also

Comment: This plugin is not compatible with newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrey Lavrukhin suggested, there is *Simple Toggle All Method Breakpoint*, install it through Settings -> Plugins. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you'll be able to do what you want is to set method breakpoints on each and every method with the class in question.  You need to click on the left hand gutter next to the method - a little red circle with 4 dots will appear and you may get a warning saying method level breakpoints can impact performance.  You can then further configure the breakpoint (by rightclicking on it, or select shift+F8) and set it so that it breaks on entry, exit or both

I'm afraid theres no way to do this in a single step/setting.