# How to view the line by line execution flow of app in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

We can use debugger in android studio and set breakpoints for the lines we want to check but if i want to see what lines are being executed orderwise **and skipping iterating through the lines of code of system classes like `Activity.java`, `Fragment.java`, `Looper.java`, `Handler.java`** *How can I do that*.

Also I would not like to set the breakpoints and see the debugger going through the execution of the app and highlight the lines that are being executed as I launch the app and click buttons.

Comment: [Logging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) would be one option, but then you need to add logs to the methods you want to see in the results.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Logging would require a lot of extra work I need a solution to do it using debugger

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you need and don't want, you can use Logpoints instead of breakpoints. To do that, set breakpoints where you want to see if your code gets called. Then right-click on those break points and un-tick the suspend option. That will bring up a more extensive menu. From there you select "Log message to console". You execute your code and see all the logpoints accessed in your console.

Comment: How to add logpoints to all the methods? Do we need to add these logpoints one by one, that will be a pain.

Comment: @IshaanKumar If you want a log for every method I'd suggest you create a convenience method that logs a message and copy paste it inside your methods. It's still a pain to do it but that way you can also personalise the message printed depending on the method

Comment: Found a way https://stackoverflow.com/a/47052165/4922328