# Pause Flutter app in debugger and wait for tap in IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, flutter, dart

I'm trying to debug a Flutter app in the Android emulator by pausing it, tapping on a button and expecting the debugger to take me to the buttons `onPressed` event handler, where I want to step through the code.

When I tap the button, nothing happens and the debugger doesn't change from paused to running. However, if I resume the app after tapping the button, the `onPressed` event handler is immediately invoked, so obviously the tap is being picked up by the emulator while the app was paused.

How can I debug my app in this manner, instead of manually finding the correct `.dart` file and the correct button and inserting a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do exactly that. Pausing the app prevents the event loop from executing and your button handler is not called. Making it pause in any of your code requires a new feature in which IntelliJ can differentiate between your code and framework code, and stop at any invocation of your code (even then, it should ignore your `build()` functions). The closest thing to that I could find in IntelliJ is [Java method breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47052165/679553), which would not work with Dart.

However, here is one thing you can do: You can set up a breakpoint in the caller of `onPressed`, which would pause your app on any button press. Here's where you can place that breakpoint:

```
// This is Line 504 of flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart
// Ctrl+click on button to go into the framework code 
// and find this file in project explorer
  void _handleTap(BuildContext context) {
    _currentSplash?.confirm();
    _currentSplash = null;
    updateHighlight(false);
    if (widget.onTap != null) {
      if (widget.enableFeedback)
        Feedback.forTap(context);
      widget.onTap(); // <---PLACE BREAKPOINT HERE
    }
  }
```

Once you hit this breakpoint, click step into (F7) a couple of times and you should get to your `onPressed`.