# IntelliJ debugging - How to watch a variable throughout its lifecycle?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I'm working on a SpringBoot like service, and using IntelliJ idea. There are some objects that are instantiated at service startup and undergo numerous method calls in multiple classes throughout the lifecycle of each API call.

With IntelliJ's debugging features, I can watch such a variable at any breakpoint, but is there a way to follow a variable's journey as it's passed around and watch all state mutations and method calls happening to it?

Answer (score 5):

You can try using field watchpoints, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html. It allows to stop where the field is accessed and/or modified:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! 
I'm sorry I wasn't clear in the question. 
Adding a field watchpoint at a given line in the code lets us watch the object as it is accessed or modified. But to follow it's journey as it's passed across classes all over the code, i'd have to add watchpoints at every place where that object is referenced / accessed / modified. Is there a way to watch an object by letting the IDE know only *what* object I want to watch, not *where* I want to watch it (because I want to watch it everywhere).

Comment: You can try adding a wildcard method breakpoint for the object's class using * as a method name. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47052165/5276012) This will stop in every method of the class. Then you can also add instance filter to track only one specific object. (Instance id is a number shown after @ in variable representation) If the object is modified only using it's methods this should help.

Comment: doesnt seem the case in IntelliJ for mac

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Make Object ID](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Setting_Labels_to_Variables_Objects_and_Watches.html) to track the object values. 
Or use [data breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_Breakpoints.html#data-breakpoints) to monitor the variable changes.