# Find all calls to interface implementers?

Tags: java, eclipse

There are a large number of classes in this codebase which use a specific interface.  However, picking a few at random, I've been unable to find one which is actually called anywhere; as such, I don't have a great idea of how to use it.

Is there a way in Eclipse to find every *instance* of any class which implements this interface?

In other words, suppose there exists an interface `Interface`, and classes `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC`, ..., `ClassX`,  which all implement it.  I want to see every point in the code where something like `ClassX obj = new ClassX().  Most of the classes I'm finding that implement this interface *don't* have any point where they're actually used; I assume they're for future use.

Comment: Maybe deleting or commenting the interface will produce the errors in classes which are implementing the interface?

Comment: **1)** Is `CTRL`+`SHITF`+`G` (find usages) not enough? You can use it on a method to see the places where it's called, or on the interface to see who is referencing it. Alternatively `CTRL`+`ALT`+`H` opens the call hierarchy view. **2)** Regarding them being unused, perhaps they're just used to expose an API, or maybe the concrete implementations are injected through DI (eg, spring).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, highlight the interface name and hit F4 or right click -> Open type hierarchy.

Update after OP's edit:

If you are using a framework that uses dependency injection like spring probably you don't find any reference because some of the implementations are defined in a xml file.

Also consider if some implementations are created and invoked via reflection.

Comment: Clarifying question now.

Answer (score 1):

Open the interface class, hold Control and move your mouse to interface's name, select open implementation. That's the simplest and easiest way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Some classes might be loaded during runtime e.g. using reflection. To *catch-them-all* you can set a method entry breakpoint on the interface method. This is explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685445/add-a-method-breakpoint-to-all-methods-of-a-class-in-eclipseide). That way all calls to implementation methods will suspend the JVM regardless of what is the object type.

[image: Method Breakpoint]

Do note that unlike the line breakpoints the method breakpoints will really slow down the performance of the JVM.